# How to pass boolean values to a PowerShell script from a command prompt

Tags: scripting, powershell

I have to invoke a PowerShell script from a batch file. One of the arguments to the script is a boolean value:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile -File .\RunScript.ps1 -Turn 1 -Unify $false
```

The command fails with the following error:

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Unify'. Cannot convert value "System.String" to type "System.Boolean", parameters of this type only accept booleans or numbers, use $true, $false, 1 or 0 instead.

At line:0 char:1
+  <<<< <br/>
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [RunScript.ps1], ParentContainsErrorRecordException <br/>
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,RunScript.ps1
```

As of now I am using a string to boolean conversion inside my script. But how can I pass boolean arguments to PowerShell?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It appears that powershell.exe does not fully evaluate script arguments when the `-File` parameter is used. In particular, the `$false` argument is being treated as a string value, in a similar way to the example below:

```
PS> function f( [bool]$b ) { $b }; f -b '$false'
f : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'b'. Cannot convert value 
"System.String" to type "System.Boolean", parameters of this type only accept 
booleans or numbers, use $true, $false, 1 or 0 instead.
At line:1 char:36
+ function f( [bool]$b ) { $b }; f -b <<<<  '$false'
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [f], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,f
```

Instead of using `-File` you could try `-Command`, which will evaluate the call as script:

```
CMD> powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command .\RunScript.ps1 -Turn 1 -Unify $false
Turn: 1
Unify: False
```

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079413/how-to-pass-boolean-values-to-powershell-script-from-command-prompt/5079574#5079574) suggests, using a switch argument would also be more idiomatic, simplifying the call by removing the need to pass a boolean value explicitly:

```
CMD> powershell.exe -NoProfile -File .\RunScript.ps1 -Turn 1 -Unify
Turn: 1
Unify: True
```

Comment: For those (like me) who have to keep the "-File" parameter, and can't change to a switch argument, but do have control over the string values that are sent, then the simplest solution is to convert the parameter to a boolean using [System.Convert]::ToBoolean($Unify); the string values must then be "True" or "False".

Comment: In order for `[System.Convert]::ToBoolean($Unify)` to evaluate to true, $Unify must -eq "true" or "True". Otherwise, `[System.Convert]::ToBoolean($Unify)` evaluates to false.

Answer (score 247):

A more clear usage might be to use switch parameters instead. Then, just the existence of the Unify parameter would mean it was set.

Like so:

```
param (
  [int] $Turn,
  [switch] $Unify
)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. To further the discussion, you can set a default value like any other parameter like so: `[switch] $Unify = $false`

Comment: I overlooked this answer, as I was sure Boolean was the way to go. It is not. Switch encapsulates the functionality of the boolean, and stops these kind of errors: " Cannot convert value "False" to type "System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute". Switches worked for me.

Comment: @MarioTacke If you don't specify the switch parameter when invoking the script then it is automatically set to `$false`. So there's no need to explicitly set a default value.

Comment: This suggestion worked very well; was able to update one of the params from [bool] to [switch] and this successfully allowed me to pass the argument via Task Scheduler.

Answer (score 20):

This is an older question, but there is actually an answer to this in the PowerShell documentation. I had the same problem, and for once RTFM actually solved it. Almost.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe

Documentation for the -File parameter states that 
"In rare cases, you might need to provide a Boolean value for a switch parameter. To provide a Boolean value for a switch parameter in the value of the File parameter, enclose the parameter name and value in curly braces, such as the following: -File .\Get-Script.ps1 {-All:$False}"

I had to write it like this:

```
PowerShell.Exe -File MyFile.ps1 {-SomeBoolParameter:False}
```

So no '$' before the true/false statement, and that worked for me, on PowerShell 4.0

Comment: Thank you for sharing! Solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: The link in the answer seems to have had its content changed.  However, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30523948/switch-parameters-and-powershell-exe-file-parameter)

Comment: Current documentation link [about_powershell.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-Microsoft.PowerShell.Core) alternatively just rung `powershell -h`.

Comment: I'm surprised that this awkward workaround ever worked - it doesn't in Windows PowerShell v5.1 (neither with nor without a leading `$`); also note that it is no longer necessary in PowerShell _Core_. I've asked for the documentation to be corrected; see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/4964

Answer (score 19):

Try setting the type of your parameter to `[bool]`:

```
param
(
    [int]$Turn = 0
    [bool]$Unity = $false
)

switch ($Unity)
{
    $true { "That was true."; break }
    default { "Whatever it was, it wasn't true."; break }
}
```

This example defaults `$Unity` to `$false` if no input is provided.

**Usage**

```
.\RunScript.ps1 -Turn 1 -Unity $false
```

Comment: Emperor XLII's answer and your comment on it regarding the `-File` parameter should cover every aspect of the original question. I'll leave my answer because someone may also find my hint on providing a default value useful.

Comment: Well done Filburt.  Your answer caused me to check my script, which already has default specified as the required value $false (I wrote that several years ago and had forgotten all about it) - so I don't even have to specify the problematic boolean parameter on the command line now. Excellent :)

Answer (score 7):

I think, best way to use/set boolean value as parameter is to use in your PS script it like this:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][ValidateSet("true", "false")][string]$deployApp="false"   
)

$deployAppBool = $false
switch($deployPmCmParse.ToLower()) {
    "true" { $deployAppBool = $true }
    default { $deployAppBool = $false }
}
```

So now you can use it like this:

```
.\myApp.ps1 -deployAppBool True
.\myApp.ps1 -deployAppBool TRUE
.\myApp.ps1 -deployAppBool true
.\myApp.ps1 -deployAppBool "true"
.\myApp.ps1 -deployAppBool false
#and etc...
```

So in arguments from cmd you can pass boolean value as simple string :).

Answer (score 6):

Running powershell scripts on linux from bash gives the same problem. Solved it almost the same as LarsWA's answer:

Working:

```
pwsh -f ./test.ps1 -bool:true
```

Not working:

```
pwsh -f ./test.ps1 -bool=1
pwsh -f ./test.ps1 -bool=true
pwsh -f ./test.ps1 -bool true
pwsh -f ./test.ps1 {-bool=true}
pwsh -f ./test.ps1 -bool=$true
pwsh -f ./test.ps1 -bool=\$true
pwsh -f ./test.ps1 -bool 1
pwsh -f ./test.ps1 -bool:1
```

Comment: same situation here.  This is dumb.

Comment: oh no it was just one :  i missedd

Answer (score 5):

**To *summarize and complement* the existing answers**, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 (the latest and *last* version) / PowerShell (Core) 7.3.3:

[David Mohundro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5079574/45375) rightfully points that **instead of `[bool]` parameters you should use [`[switch]` parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters#switch-parameters) in PowerShell**, where the ***presence vs. absence* of the switch name (`-Unify` specified vs. *not* specified) implies its value**, which makes the original problem go away.

---

However, **on occasion you may still need to pass the switch *value explicitly***, particularly if you're constructing a command line *programmatically*:

---

**In [PowerShell *Core* 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, the **original problem** (described in [Emperor XLII's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7302626/45375)) **has been *fixed***.

That is, to pass `$true` explicitly to a `[switch]` parameter named `-Unify` you can now write:

```
pwsh -File .\RunScript.ps1 -Unify:$true  # !! ":" separates name and value, no space
```

The following values can be used: `$false`, `false`, `$true`, `true`, but note that passing `0` or `1` does *not* work.

Note how the switch name is separated from the value with `:` and there must be *no whitespace* between the two.

<sup>Note: If you declare a `[bool]` parameter instead of a `[switch]` (which you generally shouldn't), you must use the same syntax. Even though `-Unify $false` *should* work, it currently doesn't - see [GitHub issue #10838](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10838).</sup>

---

In **Windows PowerShell**, the **original problem persists**, and - given that Windows PowerShell is no longer actively developed - is **unlikely to get fixed**.

- The workaround suggested in [LarsWA's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38587297/45375) - even though it is based on [the *since corrected* official help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) as of this writing - does *not* work in v5.1
- **Using `-Command` instead of `-File` is the only effective workaround**:

```
:: # From cmd.exe
powershell -Command "& .\RunScript.ps1 -Unify:$true"
```

With `-Command` you're effectively passing a *piece of PowerShell code*, which is then evaluated as usual - and inside PowerShell passing `$true` and `$false` works (but *not* `true` and `false`, as now also accepted with `-File`).

**Caveats**:

- Using `-Command` can result in additional interpretation of your arguments, such as if they contain `$` chars. (with `-File`, arguments are *literals*).
- Using `-Command` can result in a *different exit code*.

For details, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57468523/45375).

Comment: The most complete answer. This one should be marked as an answer here

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment, @Kamarey. It's unlikely that the OP will come back and change what answer is the accepted one, but up-voting this one (which I assume you have done, thank you) will help it become more visible.

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell, boolean parameters can be declared by mentioning their type before their variable.

```
    function GetWeb() {
             param([bool] $includeTags)
    ........
    ........
    }
```

You can assign value by passing $true | $false

```
    GetWeb -includeTags $true
```

Comment: Just passing the named input arguments explicitly like that worked a treat. Thanks Ahmed

Comment: The question is about calling the PowerShell _CLI_ (`powershell.exe`) from `cmd.exe`, invoking a script that already has as `[bool]` parameter defined. You're answering an unrelated question.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar when passing a script to a function with invoke-command. I ran the command in single quotes instead of double quotes, because it then becomes a string literal. `'Set-Mailbox $sourceUser -LitigationHoldEnabled $false -ElcProcessingDisabled $true';`

Answer (score -1):

Based on my test, a default value specification does not work for a parameter that is expected to be a boolean in the Function.

You can use the [switch] type or if you really want to use boolean, you should specify default value at the start of the function like below:

```
Function nullRules {
    Param
    (
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)] $boolWins

    )
   if ([DBNull]::Value.Equals($boolWins)) {$boolWins=$false}
   ....
   ....
}
```

Comment: Based on mt testing, ([DBNull]::Value.Equals($boolWins)) returns $false whether a value is passed to $boolWins or not. Therefore, the call to set $boolWins to $false if $boolWins is $null is superfluous. If $boolWins is omitted then a default boolean value of $false is automatically assigned.

Answer (score -4):

You can also use `0` for `False` or `1` for `True`.  It actually suggests that in the error message:

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Unify'. Cannot convert value `"System.String"` to type `"System.Boolean"`, parameters of this type only accept booleans or numbers, use `$true`, `$false`, **1 or 0 instead.**

For more info, check out this MSDN article on [Boolean Values and Operators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/12/24/boolean-values-and-operators.aspx).

Comment: That does not work. It is expecting integer number 1 or 0, but passing it through `-File` interprets it as string, thus fails with same error.

Comment: This answer is wrong, as the suggestion doesn't work