# Switch parameters and powershell.exe -File parameter

Tags: powershell

According Microsoft:

> In rare cases, you might need to provide a Boolean value for a switch parameter. To provide a Boolean value for a switch parameter in the value of the File parameter, enclose the parameter name and value in curly braces, such as the following: -File .\Get-Script.ps1 {-All:$False}

I have a simple script:

```psh
[CmdletBinding()] 
Param
(
    [switch] $testSwitch
)
$testSwitch.ToBool()
```

Next I am trying to run it this way:

```psh
powershell -file .\1.ps1 {-testSwitch:$false}
```

As result I receive an error:
[image]

But if believe Microsoft it should work.

If I delete `[CmdletBinding]` attribute this error will not occur, but for some reasons `$testSwitch.ToBool()` returns False despite whether I pass `$True` or `$False`.

Why? What are the reasons of this behaviour?

Comment: This works for plain booleans, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The workaround is to not use the -File parameter:

```
c:\scripts>powershell.exe .\test.ps1 -testswitch:$true
True
c:\scripts>powershell.exe .\test.ps1 -testswitch:$false
False
```

[image]

It is also an active bug on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/742084/powershell-v2-powershell-cant-convert-false-into-swtich-when-using-file-param)

Comment: There is a difference between calling powershell from a powershell shell or from a cmd shell, and according to the screen capture and to the quoted text in the question the OP is calling it from a powershell, so this renders you answer almost unuseful.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways to make this work, for instance [expanding the string](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/scriptfanatic/2011/01/02/expanding-strings-and-environment-variables-in-powershell/):

```psh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter()]$testSwitch
)

$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($testSwitch)
```

However, you don't really need to do that. Simply run the script with or without the switch and check for the presence of the switch parameter:

```psh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [switch][bool]$testSwitch
)

$testSwitch.IsPresent
```

Demonstration:

```
C:\>powershell -File .\test.ps1 -testSwitch
True

C:\>powershell -File .\test.ps1
False
```

Comment: I really need to specify $true or $false. There are a resons for this.

Comment: What this command actually do - $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($testSwitch)?

Comment: @olegk Basically, it expands (PowerShell) expressions and variables in a string.