# Not able to Pass Switch Parameter from Command Shell Prompt

Tags: sql, powershell, command-line

I have a PowerShell script which has couple of parameters including a switch parameter.

The below command executed within PowerShell works as expected:

```
  \\localhost\Test\Code\DataPullResults.ps1 -TestName 'Test survey' -QUser 'sdasch@gmail.com' -SqlServerInstanceName localhost -SqlDatabaseName MyDatabase -Load:$True -ErrorAction Continue;
```

But when I ran the **same** command from command prompt I get an error:

```
\\localhost\Test\Code\DataPullResults.ps1 : Cannot process
argument transformation on parameter 'FullLoad'. Cannot convert value
"System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter".
Boolean parameters accept only Boolean values and numbers, such as $True,
$False, 1 or 0.
```

Below is the command which I have used to execute from the command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File \\localhost\Test\Code\DataPullResults.ps1 -TestName 'Test survey' -QUser 'sdasch@gmail.com' -SqlServerInstanceName localhost -SqlDatabaseName MyDatabase -Load:$True -ErrorAction Continue;
```

Here `Load` is a Switch Parameter.

Answer (score 1):

powershell.exe does not fully evaluate script arguments when the -`File` parameter is used ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7302626/1163423)). So you should use `-command` instead:

```
powershell.exe -Command \\localhost\Test\Code\DataPullResults.ps1 -TestName 'Test survey' -QUser 'sdasch@gmail.com' -SqlServerInstanceName localhost -SqlDatabaseName MyDatabase -Load:$True -ErrorAction Continue;
```

But beside that, note that you don't have to pass a boolean to a switch value. That means, if you omit `-Load`, `$load` will be set to `$false`. And if you pass `-Load` (without  `$true`), it will get set to `$true`.

Aslo, did you noticed, that you are calling powershell.exe twice?

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe powershell.exe
```

Comment: Yes I have used Posershell.exe twice, Which is working fine for another Scripts.

Comment: I have tried the -Command Instead of -File, Though getting same error. Any Other help

Comment: How about omitting the `$true` value?