# Powershell Parameter Seems to Truncate Value

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I have a Powershell script that runs fine in VSCode but from the Powershell Prompt, I'm getting an error. Below is the output.

```
→ C:\WINDOWS\system32› powershell.exe -file 'D:\Source\Repos\Powershell Scripts\SD-Report-Archive.ps1' -sourcePath 'D:\Archives\' -targetPath 'D:\Archives2\'
D:\Archives\
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'D:\A' because it does not exist.
At D:\Source\Repos\Powershell Scripts\SD-Report-Archive.ps1:25 char:14
+     $files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Path $sourcePath
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\A:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

As you can see on the 2nd line of the output I do a Write-Output of the parameter value that I am sending in and it's correct. When I execute Get-ChildItem it seems to truncate the value to 'D:\A' and I don't know why.

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$sourcePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [string]$targetPath
)

function Copy-FilesIntoFolders {
    param()

    Write-Output $sourcePath;

    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcePath -Recurse -File
...
}
```

Comment: Do you have the same issue if you remove the trailing backslash from your paths?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I do not. Thanks so much. I never would have thought that would have been the problem.

Comment: I just found this post that seems to be related for anyone visiting this post in the future. It may be the reason this behavior was happening. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079413/how-to-pass-boolean-values-to-a-powershell-script-from-a-command-prompt. The key statement to take in is "it appears that powershell.exe does not fully evaluate script arguments when the -File parameter is used."

Comment: It works for me from what is shown.  Maybe it's better to show the whole script.

Comment: @Tim, the linked post is unrelated (it's a separate bug); your problem is solely related to PowerShell's broken behind-the-scenes re-quoting.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for the update. Just getting back into the PowerShell scene a little more. I'm amazed at what it grown into and can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, PowerShell - of necessity - *rebuilds* the command line in order to invoke *external programs*.

Notably, most external programs don't understand *single*-quoted strings (`'...'`) via their CLI, so **after having performed its own parsing, PowerShell *re-quotes* the resulting (stringified) arguments using *double* quotes (`"..."`) *if it deems that necessary***.

**Unfortunately, this re-quoting is *broken* in several respects:**

- If the argument value doesn't contain *spaces*, *no* quoting is applied. **Values without spaces but with special characters may therefore break commands**, especially when another *shell*, such as `cmd.exe` is invoked.

  - E.g., `cmd /c echo 'a&b'` breaks, because `a&b` is ultimately passed *without* quotes, and `&` has special meaning in `cmd.exe`
- **If the argument has *embedded* double quotes (`"` chars.), the re-quoting does *not* automatically *escape* them** for syntactically correct embedding inside `"..."` or unquoted literal use:

  - E.g., `foo.exe 'Nat "King" Cole'` is translated to `foo.exe "Nat "King" Cole"` - note the lack of escaping of the inner `"` chars. - which results in a *different* string when parsed by most applications, namely `Nat King Cole` (no double quotes).
  - You have to perform escaping *manually*, *in addition to* PowerShell's own escaping requirements, if applicable: `foo.exe 'Nat \"King\" Cole'` or, with double-quoting, 
    `` foo.exe "Nat \`"King\`" Cole" `` (sic).
- Similarly - as in your case - **if the argument has spaces and ends in `\`, that trailing `\` is *not* escaped in the resulting double-quoted string**, which breaks the argument syntax:

  - E.g., `foo.exe 'a b\' c` becomes `foo.exe "a b\" c` - however, most programs - including PowerShell's own CLI - interpret the `\"` as an *escaped* `"` char. rather than the closing double quote, resulting in misinterpretation of the argument, merging it with the next argument to result in 
    `a b" c`
  - Again you have to perform escaping *manually*, by *doubling* the `\`: 
    `foo.exe 'a b\\' c`

    - Alternatively, if the argument happens to be a directory path whose trailing `\` is optional, simply omit the latter.

Comment: So I guess this is why we have to jump through hoops to send in -Command arguments via a scheduled Task I found I had to add "& then double single quote all string values, then close out the double quote at the end.

Comment: @Tim: If you're calling the PowerShell CLI (`powershell.exe`) from _outside_ of PowerShell, then different rules apply. With `-File`, you'll have to use _double_-quoted strings, but the requirement to double the trailing `\ ` still applies. Yes, passing a single piece of PowerShell code to `-Command` is a viable workaround, though there are differences in behavior, notably with respect to how the exit code is determined - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443822/45375.

Comment: thanks for the reference. That post explains a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'D:\A' because it does not exist.

The backslash (\) here looks like an escape character to me. Please try with \\

Comment: The error message stems from a PowerShell cmdlet. In PowerShell code `\ ` does _not_ function as an escape character (the backtick (`\``) serves that function).