# Cannot convert string to boolean - ansible to powershell on linux

Tags: linux, powershell, ansible

I read [this whole thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079413/how-to-pass-boolean-values-to-a-powershell-script-from-a-command-prompt) about how to pass boolean values to a parameter to powershell on Linux. Nothing worked for me.

My code in Ansible is as follows:

```
- name: Install PowerCLI
  shell: pwsh -Command "Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope AllUsers -ParticipateInCEIP:$False -Confirm:$False -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore"
```

I've used many variants, such as `-ParticipateInCEIP:False`, or `-ParticipateInCEIP False`, or `-ParticipateInCEIP $false`, but I get always the same error, that it expects boolean, but I sent string.

I am running this Ansible task against a Linux machine with Powershell installed.

Any tips on how to make it work?

Best,

Francis

Comment: Try `-ParticipateInCEIP:0` (or `-ParticipateInCEIP:([bool]0)`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you `shell: pwsh -Command "something -switch:$powershellVariable"`, with double quotes, $powershellVariable will be evaluated by the Linux shell before passing it to PowerShell.

Unless you have an actual $powershellVariable defined in your shell, it will be passed to PowerShell as `something -switch:`

Try rewriting with single quotes:

```
  shell: pwsh -Command 'Set-PowerCLIConfiguration -Scope AllUsers -ParticipateInCEIP:$False -Confirm:$False -InvalidCertificateAction Ignore'
```